# SQL datatype to store 8000 characters in a column and should also be a primary key

Tags: oracle, clob

I need a column which should store more than 4000 characters(to be exact: between 4000 to 8000). And I want that particular column to be a primary key. Since I have dependency in UI end for that particular column to be primary key.

I tried CLOB and varchar(max) but those datatypes doesn't allow primary key property.

Can anyone help me with a proper datatype which can satisfy both conditions?

I'm using Oracle SQL developer 18.3.0.277

Comment: Primary key is used to: 1) identify a single instance (row) of the entity (table) and 2) to declare a relationships between two entities. 4000k symbols should be a very verbose key for identification purpose and may be used as a description column for display purpose. Please, describe the task you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify a primary key or unique constraint on a `CLOB` column. If you try then you get the exception:

> ```
> ORA-02329: column of datatype LOB cannot be unique or a primary key
> ```

You can have a composite primary key with two `VARCHAR2(4000)` columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  value_start VARCHAR2(4000),
  value_end   VARCHAR2(4000),
  CONSTRAINT table_name__value__pk PRIMARY KEY (value_start, value_end)
);
```

Or, from Oracle 12, you can [set the system setting `MAX_STRING_SIZE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spmsu/enabling-the-new-extended-data-type-capability.html#GUID-88FB7FFD-4392-49C6-843A-45B49F8A1821) to be `extended` and can use:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  value_start VARCHAR2(8000) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

---

#### However

I would question the design choice of using a `VARCHAR2(8000)` column as a primary key as you will need to duplicate the (large) column value in all the referential constraints. Instead, make the value `UNIQUE` and provide a `IDENTITY` column which can act as the primary key with a one-to-one correspondence to the large string values.